# What is the format of the address used by buffer of system call read?

Tags: linux, system-calls, strace

I'm using strace, and the following line appears:

read(3,"\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\3\2\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\00P\265\31\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0008\0\n\0@\0G\0F\0\6\0\0\0\5\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0000\2\0\0\0\0\0\0000\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832

What is the format of the second argument? What are all those 0's,@'s and \?

I'm using Debian, with Intel i5 CPU x86_64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string is formatted using C syntax. Non-printable characters are shown using octal representation: null bytes are shown as `\0` and the ELF file magic at the beginning as `\177ELF`. The output shows what the pointer given as second argument points to after the call to `read` has completed. `= 832` at the end shows the return value.

Comment: In short, `read()` was used to read 832 bytes from an executable file, which returned 832 bytes of data.